# IllegalStateException at ThreadPoolBudget

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

На проекте используем **Jetty**.
При прогонке тестов локально - все проходят, когда начинается автоматическая сборка проекта на сервере, то часть тестов падает с ошибкой **java.lang.IllegalStateException at ThreadPoolBudget.java:156**.
После "гугла" начал думать, что в некоторый момент приложению начинает не хватать дефолтного количества потоков. После мониторинга через Jconsole обнаружилось, что их гораздо меньше.
В связи с отсутствием возможности воссоздать проблему локально, ломаю голову уже который день.
Есть ли у кого-нибудь мысли на этот счет?
Буду очень благодарен.

Версия Jetty 9.4.25.

Comment: Какое сообщение в исключении?

Comment: Какая версия jetty? Менялись ли настройки параметра `maxThreads` или используется значение по-умолчанию?

Comment: @RomanKonoval 
1) Версия  1.1.3;
2) Нет, все значения по дефолту, maxPoolSize=200, приложение использует около 60;
3) Кроме описанной ошибки, есть  название свалившегося теста, больше ничего нет(

Comment: Во-первых, дополнительную информацию с уточнениями вопроса, добавляйте в тело вопроса кнопкой "править". Во-вторых, текущая версия jetty `9.4.30`, не перепутали с версией `sping-boot`?

Comment: Как вы определили, что используется 60 потоков? Наблюдали за графиками в jconsole? Там показывает значение с периодом обновления 4 секунды (по-умолчанию). Это значение могло и вырости за 4 секунды.

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что глянул в исходники jetty (той версии, которую используете `ThreadPoolBudget.java:156`), чтобы точно знать почему бросается исключение. Чтобы исправлять проблему, нужно знать причину. Для этого нужно выдвинуть гипотезу и проверить ее.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, подкорректировал вопрос.
Да, мониторил график потоков в jconsole.

Comment: Причина в недостаточном количестве потоков https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.25.v20191220/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPoolBudget.java#L156  найдите способ включить логирование в https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.25.v20191220/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPoolBudget.java#L173 чтобы знать чем они заняты

Comment: Еще я бы включил access log в jetty, чтобы посмотреть, какие и сколько запросов выполнялось в момент, когда случилось исключение. Может быть, тесты действительно выполняют больше запросов, чем есть потоков в пуле.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за обсуждение, проблема была в том, что количество используемых потоков было меньше дефолтного, но помимо них весели потоки, которые отработали через Mono, вернув результат, но находились в ожидании. Собственно освобождение таких потоков решило проблему. Премного благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

Освобождение отработанных потоков решило проблему. После получения определенного скоупа ответов от потоков, вызывается метод HttmClient.stop, что и помогло решить данную проблему, спасибо **Roman Konoval** за помощь.